# Moving location of php the_title

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make the area of my content pages which houses the page title full width, so i can put an image back there, similar to this: http://www.nielsen.com/us/en/newswire.html

I've tried to move the page-title div above the container on page.php, but it always ends up back inside the container.

Here's an example of what I want moved on my site: http://www.zachkeller.net/cp_site/?page_id=93

Here's my page.php code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

            <!-- If there is no gallery, just grab the featured image -->
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
              <a class="featured-image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'okay' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large-image' ); ?></a>
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="container-wrap">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="content">
                        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="blog-post clearfix">
                                <div class="blog-inside">
                                    <div class="page-title">
                                        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                                    </div>

                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                </div><!-- blog inside -->
                            </div><!-- blog post -->
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div><!-- content -->

                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                </div><!-- container -->
            </div><!-- container wrap -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use echo get_title(); instead of the_title. That way it will output where you want it. the_title automatically outputs itself. get_title is the value that you echo manually.

Be sure to check which page template you're using. In wordpress, a good clue is to check the body class, which often includes "page-template-full-width-php" or similar which tells you which template to edit.

Comment: Ok... so how do i implement this? Replace "php the_title" with "echo get-title()"  ??

Comment: Yes, so, this has to be inside the if statement (the loop), but you just replace the_title with echo get_title(); You can also do this $title = get_title(); if you need to do anything to it before you output it. the_title automatically echos by itself, so you're doing the same thing but controlling the output.

Comment: So, the new code for that section would be:          <div class="page-title">
          <h1><?$title = get_title(); ?></h1>
         </div>

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong

Comment: You have to move the if(have_posts... line above container too.

Comment: <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

   <div class="page-title">
     <h1><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h1>
   </div>

   <div class="container-wrap">.....

Comment: get_title, with no "the" in the middle. Just "get_title()" should work.

Comment: <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

       <div class="page-title">
         <h1><?php echo get_title(); ?></h1>
       </div>

       <div class="container-wrap">....

Comment: No problem, can you explain more why it doesn't work or possibly post your page code? How do you know this is the right page? Is the page title on the blog posts page? That is index.php instead.

Comment: This is in page.php. Every time the page loads, the title is back inside the main container. Moving the title php section and the other code you mentioned has no effect at all. I want the page title to be loaded above the container so that I can make it full 100% width. Once that is done, I can adjust the padding of the title h1 tags to make it aligned correctly. I'm not sure how to post my code in these comments.

Comment: page.php is only for page content and many themes mess with templates, so it could be an entirely different page altogether. A good test is if you write something in the page, like 'blah' and see if it appears when you load that page. If it doesn't show up, you have the wrong template. I don't want to keep going back and forth on stack, but I'd love to help you work this out. Email me if you want to talk more and I can help. me@rncrtr.in